# Hide class implementation using static lib c++

Tags: c++

I am working on a project and I need to make a class which I will share using a static library. So far I wrote the implementation inside a .cpp file and shared only de .h and .lib files. If I use those inside another project and I try to debug something that uses my class I am able to see the full implementation written in the .cpp file. Is there any way I could hide the implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I use those inside another project and I try to debug something that uses my class I am able to see the full implementation written in the .cpp file. Is there any way I could hide the implementation?

You can only see the implementation in `.cpp` because:

1. `.lib` has debug information not stripped.
2. `.cpp` file happens to be in a location mentioned in the debug information (i.e. there is no copy of `.cpp` inside `.lib`).

If you remove any of the above conditions you won't be able to see the source in the debugger.

Comment: So, this has to do with building the .lib in debug mode? Is there a way I can build the .lib in release mode, but still be able to use in debug mode (in current project)?

Comment: @valentin.ciprian Switching between debug/release depends on your build system. You may like to get familiar with the build system you use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [pimpl](https://cpppatterns.com/patterns/pimpl.html) idiom to hide the implementation.By switching to pimpl idiom, you can change your implementation anytime without affecting the way your client uses library.

But to your question, if you are distributing your header and library file only, then others won't be able to see your implementation. The library has embedded info about your source files in your machine. That's why you are able to debug like that.